# How to get back to ajax state with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is the [application](http://flyerboard.medicine.yale.edu/profiles/last_name/a/?site=3)  on which i am working.

When user clicks on any alphabet the the respective data is loaded through ajax call. And profile of associated faculty is displayed. When user clicks on back to list buttion the page goes back to the previous page rather than page of selected alphabet.

What i want to do is ,

When user clicks on back to list button user have to go the aphabet selected ajax call ?

How can i  do this ?

Comment: you have to store somewhere which link is clicked

Comment: When a user click on an alphabet store the alphabet value in a hidden input. Now when clicking on the **Back to List** button, get the stored value in the hidden input and make the Ajax call.

Comment: A case for the History API?  Try here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history